# Android Application keeps stopping as I requested location

Tags: java, android, android-location

I am new to Android Studio, I know that, it  cannot be an excuse but I need your help

I added two request statements in Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.escaper.lehome">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

On my activity java file I have location manager, I am trying to get Latitude and Longitude and pass them to TextView.

```
package com.example.escaper.lehome;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        if (location != null) {
            Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            // We have location data
            TextView tvLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLat);
            tvLat.setText(latitude.toString());

            TextView tvLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLong);
            tvLong.setText(longitude.toString());

        } else {
            // We don't have location data
        }

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

However, Application keeps stopping.

Updated LogCat , after crashing was fixed, however still cannot display location

```
03-19 23:17:16.325 9261-9261/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
03-19 23:17:16.325 9261-9261/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
03-19 23:17:16.574 9261-9261/com.example.escaper.lehome W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.escaper.lehome-1/lib/x86
03-19 23:17:16.673 9261-9291/com.example.escaper.lehome I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up
03-19 23:17:16.674 9261-9261/com.example.escaper.lehome I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
03-19 23:17:16.684 9261-9291/com.example.escaper.lehome E/GMPM: getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10
03-19 23:17:16.685 9261-9291/com.example.escaper.lehome E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
03-19 23:17:16.752 9261-9261/com.example.escaper.lehome W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-19 23:17:16.947 9261-9300/com.example.escaper.lehome I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-19 23:17:16.947 9261-9300/com.example.escaper.lehome D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-19 23:17:16.947 9261-9300/com.example.escaper.lehome W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-19 23:17:16.947 9261-9300/com.example.escaper.lehome D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
03-19 23:17:17.019 9261-9261/com.example.escaper.lehome W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

Comment: Did you request the permission at run-time? Newer Android versions require this. See the documentation for details.

Comment: @Ninja - please do not update this question if you have another problem. Accept the answer which was helpful and ask a new question instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is created by this line:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

if you call a function like `getSystemService` which needs `Context`, you cannot new them as class member like this. You **must** do it when `Context` is created, for example in `onCreate()`. So your code need to be like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ...
}
```

I have not checked all of your code and you may find other bugs too, but this part is obviously incorrect.

Comment: This is the correct answer (because one can find the following line in Logcat: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()")

Comment: Thank you, my application stopped crashing. However, still it cannot display my location. I am testing it on my phone, not on virtual device. It does not even ask for permission when starts . Should I create something like a dialogue, so user can permit the app to use device's location .

Comment: @Ninja my suggestion? Read how to use Location Services correctly. You need to change your code a lot. Read tutorials here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html or this one: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html